# SQL query in MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb

I just want to this simple thing but eclipse wont let me use the find() method, i cant see why cuz this is the way its explained at mongodb.org.. can someone see what im doing wrong? its the folk.find() method, it works as long as i dont put any condition in there( namn:"Robert")

```
Mongo mongo= new Mongo();
DB db = mongo.getDB("Helly");
long startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
DBCollection folk = db.getCollection("folk");
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
document.put("namn", "Robert");
document.put("efternamn", "Brismo");
document.put("ålder", 34);

BasicDBObject documentDetail = new BasicDBObject();
documentDetail.put("ålder", 47);
documentDetail.put("hårfärg", "brun");
documentDetail.put("skostorlek", "44");

document.put("Utseende", documentDetail);
folk.insert(document);
DBCursor cursor= folk.find({namn:"Robert"});
while(cursor.hasNext()){
DBObject obj=cursor.next();
System.out.println(obj);}
```

Comment: What Java documentation on mongodb.org showed `find` in the way you show? JavaScript would work that way.

Comment: oh ok so this is for javascript..? do you know if there is a way of doing this in Java? I have a bunch of SQL queries for my SQL database and want to use the same questions in mongoDB since i moved my data from SQL server to Mongo. Do you have any advice? im using java in eclipse now.

Comment: I added an answer for how to do a find in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a find with a query on `namn`, you need to use an instance of `BasicDBObject` and use that as the query:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("namn", "Robert");
DBCursor cursor= folk.find(query);
try {
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
       // .. do something
       System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
}
finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

[Getting Started Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use QueryBuilder class as follows.

```
// Connect to the Mongo database
Mongo mongoConn = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB mongoDb = mongoConn.getDB("TESTDB");
DBCollection collection = mongoDb.getCollection("folk");

// Building the query parameters
QueryBuilder qFinder= new QueryBuilder();
qFinder.put("name").is("Robert");

// Fetching the records for the query. get() method will convert QueryBuilder -&gt; DBObject class of query parameters
DBCursor dbCursor = collection.find(qFinder.get());

while(dbCursor.hasNext()) {
// Do something with the code
System.out.println(dbCursor.next());
}
```

The Advantage with querybuilder is that you can chain queries easily e.g. qFinder.put("name").is("Robert").and("age").gt(25); and so on.
Refer: [My Blog Post](https://dpancs.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/mongodb-java-driver-querybuilder-class/)